# Code behind for a flex application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm working on Flex project and having problems with "connecting" the code-behind to the mxml file (It actually worked before in another project). Both files are in the default package.

**Hydw.mxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" xmlns="*">

    <s:TextArea id="txt_log" x="34" y="171" width="225" height="217"/>
</s:Application>
```

**Hydw.as:**

```
package  
{
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.external.*;
    import flash.media.*;

    import mx.controls.TextArea;
    import mx.core.*;
    import mx.events.*;

    import spark.components.*;

    public class Hydw extends spark.components.Application
    {

        public var txt_log:spark.components.TextArea;

        public function Hydw ()
        {
            super();

            addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, this.creationCompleteHandler);
        }

        private function creationCompleteHandler(param1:FlexEvent) : void
        {
            WriteToLog("creationCompleteHandler");
        }

       public function WriteToLog(s:String) : void 
       {
           txt_log.text += s + "\n";
       }
```

I run the application (after releasing) and I see nothing in the TextArea. Why?
By the way, I'm having trouble with the debugging for now, so I can't tell where's the failure exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want

**Hydw.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<abstract:Hydw xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               xmlns:abstract="test.pack.abstract.*" 
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:TextArea id="txt_log" x="34" y="171" width="225" height="217"/>
</abstract:Hydw>
```

and your **Hydw.as:**

```
package test.pack.abstract
{
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    import spark.components.Application;
    import spark.components.TextArea;

    [Bindable]
    public class Hydw extends Application
    {

        public var txt_log:TextArea;

        public function Hydw()
        {
            super();
            addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, init);
        }

        public function init(evt:FlexEvent):void
        {


        }

    }
}
```

any visual component used in **.mxml** code you want to use in **.as** class
must be declared as public binded variable in your **.as** class or simply declare your **.as** class as **[Bindable]**

That's All

Answer (score 2):

Obviously it didn't work. There need to make some changes in ActionScript and mxml file.

**First:** Remove package and class from ActionScript file like:

```
import mx.events.FlexEvent;

public function creationCompleteHandler(param1:FlexEvent) : void
{
    WriteToLog("creationCompleteHandler");
}

public function WriteToLog(s:String) : void 
{
    txt_log.text += s + "\n";
}
```

Because It is in **default package**  there isn't required to defined package and class.

**Second:**

Remove `public var txt_log:spark.components.TextArea;` from as file. Because it will conflict `txt_log` with id of textArea in mxml file.

**Third:**

Remove `addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, this.creationCompleteHandler);` from as file and give creation complete event in mxml file. like:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>

    <fx:Script source="Hydw.as" />

        <s:TextArea id="txt_log" x="34" y="171" width="225" height="217"/>
</s:Application>
```

And another thing is you forget to include as file inside mxml. like:

```
<fx:Script source="Hydw.as" />
```

Hope you understand and help to move forward.

Comment: Thank you,but I insist to stay with the current structure. There must be something I'm missing. I don't want to inject the code, but rather connect it to the mxml file as I did before. There are plenty of example online which demonstrate it, yet it didn't work for me.

Comment: I don't understand what you need. what trouble you getting while connect?

Comment: Please look at the example: http://examples.pmwilliams.co.uk/adobeblog/presentationpatterns/codebehind/CodeBehind.html (You can "View Source"). I want to do something similar but with the `<s:Application>`. Meaning, I want to connect to `<s:Application>` to the code-behind.